# How to reset javascript speech recognition after every word

Tags: javascript

I want to reset the result after every word so when I say "hi" the video will play "how are you" another video will play, but the problem is everytime I try to say hi the code stop and don't let me say somthing else till I refresh the page. is there is any chance to make it refresh/clear/reset the result

can anyone help me please.
thank you

```js
var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
var SpeechRecognitionEvent = SpeechRecognitionEvent || webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent;

var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = true;
recognition.lang = 'en-US';
recognition.interimResults = false;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;

var diagnostic = document.querySelector('.output');
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

document.body.onload = function() {
  recognition.start();
}

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  var res = event.results[0][0].transcript;
  diagnostic.textContent = 'Result received: ' + res + '.';
  
  if (res == 'hi') {
    vid.play();
  } else if (res == 'stop') {
    vid.pause();
  }
}

recognition.onspeechend = function() {
  location.reload();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>Speech color changer</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <video id="myVideo" width="100%" controls autoplay loop muted="muted">
      <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
    <p class="hints"></p>
    <div>
        <p class="output"><em>...diagnostic messages</em></p>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an event listener after the video play finished like the following:

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',function() {
  recognition.start();
},false);
```

Comment: Okay, but how can this help with refreshing the "onresult function"?
I want to say something eles after finishing the speech not the video

Comment: Then you need 
`recognition.addEventListener('audioend', function() { 
  recognition.start()
});`